# Linux SVN post-commit doesn't work?

Tags: linux, shell, svn, svn-hooks

I read and try alot of Blog an Post entries from stackoverflow and other pages, but there was no solution.

**SVN Version** : 1.6.11
**Linux Version** : Linux 2.6.32-358.23.2.el6.x86_64 x86_64

I've created a script, which should be execute after a svn commit.

I've renamed the file `post-commit.tmpl` to `post-commit`.
I use absolut paths and all files (the script, post-commit, log..) are in mode `777`.
In the script and in the `post-commit` the `PATH` is set.
When I commit something in my Project, my debug.log is working .

```
echo "START">>/svn/test/debug.log
sudo echo /svn/test/hookScripts/generateDocumentation.sh "$1" "$2">>./svn/test/error.log
echo "END">>/svn/test/debug.log
```

There are the `START` and `END` entries in the `debug.log` File, but the script won't be executed.

I tried some from [this link](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/run-execute-sh-shell-script/), but it doesn't work.

Comment: I'm not certain what you try to achieve there.  Did you mean to append a line `/svn/test/hookScripts/generateDocumentation.sh "$1" "$2"` to the file `./svn/test/error.log` (which you can only open as root)?  Or did you mean to run `/svn/test/hookScripts/generateDocumentation.sh "$1" "$2"` with root privileges, appending the output of that command to `./svn/test/error.log`?

Comment: Also, note that you don't use an absolute path for `./svn/test/error.log`.

Comment: exactly. I want to run the `/svn/test/hookScripts/generateDocumentation.sh`and appendng the output of the command to `./svn/test/error.log`. The owner of all files is the root user, and all files hold the mode `777`

Comment: Then you probably should remove the `echo` in `sudo echo /svn/test/hookScripts/generateDocumentation.sh`.

Comment: @ex-bart Good Morning :D the Prolem was: I have to run the script in a file, so I've to call it with `$(.......)` now it works!! `echo $(./svn/doctest/hookScripts/generateDocumentation.sh "$1" "$2")>>/svn/doctest/error.log`

Comment: I don't think enclosing the command in `$(...)` solved anything.  It's much more likely that the solution is one of the other changes you made: changing the path of the output file (including making it absolute), changing the path of the script (making it relative), omitting `sudo` (not sure whether you actually did the last one, your comment suggests that but is not 100% clear on that point).

Answer (score 0):

The Problem was: I try to run `/svn/test/hookScripts/generateDocumentation.sh` in a script. To execute this I've to write it in **`$(...)`**